# Js return wrong sum result

Tags: javascript, sum

In JS  `9007199254740992 + 1` should be `9007199254740993`.

I'm getting `9007199254740992`.

What's going on here?

```js
console.log(9007199254740992 + 1)
// 9007199254740992
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: You can use BigInt()

Comment: @iBug Sorry, here i have not used floating numbers right? still why we get wrong values? still if js treats somehow as float, is there any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BigInts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) to prevent overflow like this.

```js
console.log((9007199254740992n + 1n).toString())
```

Or, if it's a variable:

```js
const num = "9007199254740992";
console.log((BigInt(num) + 1n).toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

From MDN:

> Double precision floating point format only has 52 bits to represent the mantissa, so it can only safely represent integers between -(2<sup>53</sup> – 1) and 2<sup>53</sup> – 1.

> "Safe" in this context refers to the ability to represent integers exactly and to compare them correctly. For example, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1 === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2 will evaluate to true, which is mathematically incorrect. See Number.isSafeInteger() for more information.

If you really want to use numbers larger than that one you can use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was trying to make them superscript text. But it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

`9007199254740992` is the largest allowed integer in JS `(2^53 – 1)`

[Check here for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER#:%7E:text=The%20Number.,larger%20integers%2C%20consider%20using%20BigInt%20.)

Alternatively you can use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: `(2^53 – 1)` is `Number.MAXIMUM_SAFE_INTEGER` but it is `9007199254740991` not `9007199254740992 `. And anyway, larger integers are also allowed. For example, `Number.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Please fix the max safe number value.

Answer (score -2):

Try to shrink the number, Javascript has a hard time processing large values. Or if you don't want to, turn the big number into a value.

```
const bigNum = 9007199254740992;
console.log(bigNum + 1);
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP is trying to do that doesn't work.